# Probability density function. Find $k$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = kxy$, for $0 ≤ x, y ≤ 1,$ otherwise $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0$.

(a) Determine $k$ such that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a PDF.

Comment: Reminder: A property of PDF is such that its integral over its domain equals *what*. Apply your calculus. I think you know what the *what* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selected from [PDF at WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

> The probability density function is nonnegative everywhere, and its integral over the entire space is equal to one.

As implied, $\int_{R^2} f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$. (Property of PDF)

Thus $\int_0^1\int_0^1 kxy dxdy=1$, with the rest being mere integration.

Comment: k = 4? :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @Panda Yep, that's the answer. Harder questions involve triangular or circular area of integration which will just complicate integration, though-- e.g. $0<=x<=y<=1$.